# wordpress add_rewrite_rule not navigating to correct page

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change this url in: "http://example.com/class-schedules?selectedCatId=52" to become: "http://example.com/class-schedules/classCSCP" , but it navigates to incorrect page. Any help !!

I used this method in order to rewrite the url

```
function events_custom_rewrite() {
add_rewrite_rule("class-schedules/classCPA/?", 'index.php?page_id=4321&selectedCatId=52', 'top');
}
```

Comment: Incorrect page? Or 404 page??

Comment: @cgee its navigating to the page 4321 but with considering the parameter   selectedCatId

Answer (score 0):

You need the `add_rewrite_tag` too.

Please include this code and clear the permalink cache in your settings.

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%selectedCatId%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^class-schedules/classCPA/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=4321&selectedCatId=$matches[1]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

With this code you should (**I didn't test it!**) access your site like this:

http://example.com/class-schedules/classCPA/52

And in your theme you can access the variable like this:

```
global $wp_query;
$selectedCatId = $wp_query->query_vars['selectedCatId']; //52
```

> IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules
>   database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens,
>   Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any
>   changes.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag
https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: IMPORTANT: Do not forget to flush and regenerate the rewrite rules database after modifying rules. From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Comment: still facing same issue